# how can i get data from user when he click the add button?

Tags: python, sqlite, kivy, kivymd

this is the main app:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
import sqlite3

class Vinylapp(MDApp):
    connection = None
    cur = None
    connection = sqlite3.connect("vinyl.db")
    cur = connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS Vinyl(
        name TEXT,
        alboum TEXT,
        song TEXT)
        """)        
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()

    def vinyl_add(name,alboum,song):
        connection = sqlite3.connect("vinyl.db")
        cur = connection.cursor()
        connection.execute("INSERT INTO Vinyl VALUES (?,?,?)",(name, alboum, song))
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()
Vinylapp().run()
```

and here is the kivy file code:

main screen

```
MDScreen:
    bg: app.theme_cls.bg_light
    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        pos_hint: {"bottom": 1}
        title: "Search By Name "
        elevation: 10
        md_bg_color: [0/255, 200/255, 0/255, 1]
        right_action_items: [['magnify', lambda x: app.search_menu.app]]
    MDLabel:
        text:"ADD VINYL"
        halign:"center"
        font_style: "Button"
        font_size: 20
        pos_hint:{"center_x":.5,"center_y":.8}
    MDTextField:  
        hint_text:"Composer Name"
        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.6}
        size_hint_x:.3
        current_hint_text_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
        color_mode: 'custom'
        line_color_focus: [0/255, 200/255, 0/255, 1]
    MDTextField:
        hint_text:"Song Name"
        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.4}
        size_hint_x:.3
        current_hint_text_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
        color_mode: 'custom'
        line_color_focus: [0/255, 200/255, 0/255, 1]
    MDTextField: 
        hint_text:"Alboum Name"
        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.5}
        size_hint_x:.3
        current_hint_text_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
        color_mode: 'custom'
        line_color_focus: [0/255, 200/255, 0/255, 1]
```

and the button

```
    MDRaisedButton:
        text:"ADD"
        pos_hint: {"center_x":.5, "center_y":.23}
        size_hint_x: 0.3
        text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        md_bg_color: [0/255, 200/255, 0/255, 1]
        on_press: app.vinyl_add()
```

Comment: MDRaisedButton: text:"ADD" pos_hint: {"center_x":.5, "center_y":.23} size_hint_x: 0.3 text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1 md_bg_color: [0/255, 200/255, 0/255, 1] on_press: app.vinyl_add()  this is the button

Comment: Is the `ADD` Button part of the main screen?

Comment: @JohnAnderson yes it is

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Use `ids` to reference the `MDTextField`. Make the following changes to the Python script and kv file.

### main.py

Need to add `self` into method `vinyl_add` because it is defined as a method of the `MDApp` class.

#### Snippets

```
    def vinyl_add(self, name, alboum, song):
        print(name, alboum, song)
        ...
```

### kv file

1. Add `ids` to the `MDTextField:` so that you are reference them.

#### Snippets

```
    MDTextField:
        id: composer
        hint_text:"Composer Name"
        ...
    MDTextField:
        id: song
        hint_text:"Song Name"
        ...
    MDTextField:
        id: album
        hint_text:"Alboum Name"
```

2. Pass the text value of the `MDTextField:` as parameters to the function call.

#### Snippets

```
    MDRaisedButton:
        text:"ADD"
        ...
        on_press: app.vinyl_add(composer.text, album.text, song.text)
```

### Output:

#### KivyMD App - Add Vinyl

[image: KivyMD - Add Vinyl]

#### SQLite DB: `vinyl.db`

[image: vinyl.db]

Comment: thx very much but how i can  insert this into my db

Comment: [If you want to say "thank you", vote on or accept that person's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). When the method `vinyl_add(...)` is invoked, it will add into the database, `vinyl.db`.